# Subsetting data.table set by date range in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset, date-range, slice

I have a large dataset in data.table that I'd like to subset by a date range. My data set looks like this:

```
testset <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04",
                                     "2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), 
                      yr = c(2013,2013,2013,2013,2013), 
                      mo = c(07,08,09,10,11),
                      da = c(02,03,04,05,06), 
                      plant = LETTERS[1:5], 
                      product = as.factor(letters[26:22]), 
                      rating = runif(25))
```

I'd like to be able to choose a date range directly from the `as.Date` column without using the `yr`, `mo`, or `da` columns. Currently, I'm subsetting by `mo` and it's extremely clunky at times, especially when years switch over. A more elegant method of doing this would make my life infinitely easier.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Why not:

```
testset[date>="2013-08-02" & date<="2013-11-01"]
```

Answer (score 23):

See also:

```
?`%between%`
```

Works like this:

```
testset[date %between% c("2013-08-02", "2013-11-01")]
```

Comment: good point @scottyaz - To clarify to others %between% is part of data.table package. see ?between when package loaded. So if you are going DT route, then it is not too big a sin.

Answer (score 9):

You mentioned that you are subsetting, but its not clear whether you are using the subset fn in R.

Type ?subset into the R console to see the details of the subset() function in R which 'returns a subset of vectors, matrices or data frames which meet conditions'. Then use part of the method that Troy posted above to choose the date range

```
thisYear <- subset(testset, date > "2015-01-01" & date < "2015-12-31")
```

Comment: Hi, 
I'm getting following error : 
In Ops.factor(date, "2015-01-01") : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors